# How to set overflow hidden but without affecting certain elements

Tags: css

I have a `div` with overflow hidden set up in order to cut an image:

[image]

The image on the right (the device) but it's affecting the popup on the left which MUST be there.

```
.hero {
    position: relative;
    padding: 32px 0 0;
    min-height: 504px;
    background: #D91A37 url(../images/flagscape-bg.jpg) 0 0/cover no-repeat;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

That popup already has z-index applied but it is not working due to the overflow hidden on that red background div.

So, is there a way to make that rule and not touching at all the popup on the left?

Comment: Which is the css for popup? I think you should use absolute or fixed position for it

Comment: absolute position your popup

Comment: You can position the popup in relation to a parent of `.hero` instead, so it won't be affected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `position: absolute` for your popup so that the properties defined on the parent are not inherited by the popup.

Your code should be something like:

```
.popup {
  position: absolute:
  top: 50px;
  left: 20px;
  z-index: 10;
}
```

And provide `position: relative` to a general parent above `hero` and `popup`.